# Why won't cy.intercept/cy.wait catch my HTTP request?

Tags: unit-testing, xmlhttprequest, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am attempting to write a Cypress (v13.1.0) unit test and use `cy.intercept` to catch an HTTP `GET` call.  This `GET` call happens after the user presses a button.  Based on reading documentation, I setup my test in the following order: `cy.intercept`-{userActionHere}-`cy.wait`.  However, the `GET` call never gets intercepted.

Example:

```
describe("API Tests", () => {
  it("get copy-style", () => {
    cy.intercept("GET", "http://localhost:7771/api/agent/report/copy-style").as("getStyle");

    openReport(undefined, testReport_demo);
    cy.visit("/#/");

    cy.get("rec-list").find('[data-cy="acceptButton"]').click();

    cy.wait("@getStyle").then((interception) => {
      console.log("The @getStyle result: ", interception);
    });
  });
});
```

Results in:

```
Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: getStyle. No request ever occurred.
```

I've also tried the following with the same result of no interception:

- Catch any HTTP request (e.g., `cy.intercept("**")`) but it still is not intercepted.

  - In this case a few `GET` calls for some image assets were caught, but these are irrelevant to what I want.  None of my calls to `/api/agent/**` get captured.
- Use various path variations in `cy.intercept` (e.g., "api/agent/report/copy-style", "api/agent/**", "**api**", etc.).
- Moving the `wait` before the button click.
- Increase the wait timeout (e.g., `cy.wait("@getStyle", {timeout: 30000}`)
- Use `cy.pause()` to manually click the button in the UI before the wait.
- Manually click the button during `cy.wait()`.

In all cases I can see the HTTP call being made via WireShark and/or in the browser's Network tab and the correct response data comes back, but Cypress isn't seeing it.  Saw a lot of posts mentioning `cy.server` and `cy.route` but those appear to be deprecated.  Haven't found a post yet that has helped me.

Comment: I've seen `cy.intercept("*")` as catch-all. Using a double-star `**` wildcard may not be correct as it's normally used for path segments (not the full path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue turned out to be the `--proxy-bypass-list` switch.  Unbeknownst to me, the following code was in the cypress.config.ts file:

```
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser, launchOptions) => {

        logHandler(browser, launchOptions);

        launchOptions.args = launchOptions.args.map((arg) => {
          if (arg.startsWith("--proxy-bypass-list")) {
            return "--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>,http://*localhost*:7771,ws://*localhost*:7771,ws://127.0.0.1:7771";
          }

          return arg;
        });

        return launchOptions;
      });
    }
```

For example, If I used `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`, my intercept worked.  If the address is part of the proxy bypass list then Cypress fails to see the call and therefore won't intercept.  This explains why I could see all the traffic occurring in the browser's developer tools but Cypress wouldn't catch it.

Answer (score 2):

It think your various attempts at wildcard matching are not correct

- `cy.intercept("**")` -> `cy.intercept("*")` for catch-all

When using `**` for a path segment make sure the path separator `/` is included:

- `**/api/agent/report/copy-style` for domain wildcard
- `**/api/agent/**/*` or `/api/agent/**/*` for any api/agent call
- `**/api/**/*` or `/api/**/*` for any api

Also try [Regexp](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-url)

```js
cy.intercept(/\/copy-style/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  Wasn't the "real" issue I was facing but still helpful.